# Round up to the nearest quarter hour - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to create a `select` element where time is shown:

```
            <strong>Time:</strong>
            <select name="hours" id="hours">
                <option value="1">1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
                <option value="3">3</option>
                <option value="4">4</option>
                <option value="5">5</option>
                <option value="6">6</option>
                <option value="7">7</option>
                <option value="8">8</option>
                <option value="9">9</option>
                <option value="10">10</option>
                <option value="11">11</option>
                <option value="12">12</option>
                <option value="13">13</option>
                <option value="14">14</option>
                <option value="15">15</option>
                <option value="16">16</option>
                <option value="17">17</option>
                <option value="18">18</option>
                <option value="19">19</option>
                <option value="20">20</option>
                <option value="21">21</option>
                <option value="22">22</option>
                <option value="23">23</option>
                <option value="24">24</option>
            </select>
            :
            <select name="minutes" id="minutes">
                <option value="00">00</option>
                <option value="15">15</option>
                <option value="30">30</option>
                <option value="45">45</option>
            </select>
```

In my JavaScript I'm trying to show the current time. I current have code that rounds quarter hours up or down. So, `10:25 => 10:30 & 9:18 => 9:15`.

I would like to know how to only round up instead of rounding down as well.

My JavaScript:

```
var CurrentDate=new Date();
 $("#hours").val(CurrentDate.getHours());
 $("#minutes").val((((CurrentDate.getMinutes() + 7.5)/15 | 0) * 15) % 60);
```

Comment: I just noticed, getHours() will never returns `24`

Comment: @Asenar Fixed it, thanks for notifying me!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this code:

```
var minutes = (parseInt((CurrentDate.getMinutes() / 15)) + 1) * 15;
minutes = minutes >= 60 ? minutes - 60 : minutes; 
$("#minutes").val(minutes);
```

### Explenation of code:

```
var minutes = (parseInt((CurrentDate.getMinutes() / 15)) + 1) * 15;
```

This line divides current minuts by 15 and parses result as an integer, to cut off the floating point, and adds +1 to round it up. Then multiplies by 15 to get the correct minutes of the current quarter hour

```
minutes = minutes >= 60 ? minutes - 60 : minutes;
```

Checks if the resulting minutes are greater than 60, if so subtract 60 to not "overshoot" 60 minutes

```
$("#minutes").val(minutes);
```

Sets the value on the given tag

Comment: If current time is `3:05`, `%15` will return `5`. `+1` will make it `6` and `*15 - 60` will make it `30` and not `0`. You should also incorporate something for such cases

Comment: @Rajesh true, I misunderstood how % works, fixed it now :)

Comment: Still `+1` will cause issue. Check @Asenar answer.

Comment: @Rajesh No it will not

Comment: You can do math for cases where min is `5,18,33...`

Comment: our both solutions are pretty similar (I just edited your answer to replace `minutes > 60 ? minutes = minutes - 60 : minutes = minutes; ` by  `minutes = minutes > 60 ? minutes - 60 : minutes; ` because that's the way that operator should be used :)

Comment: @RononDex `minutes` currently returns `60`

Comment: @Chris, if 60 should not be an option, replace > with >= (see edited answer)

Comment: Lets take 5. Nearest quarter is `00`. So `5/15` will return `0`. `+1` and `*15` will make it `15` and not `0`. Same goes for any value where nearest quarter is prior one

Comment: @RononDex Jup, fixed now! Thanks!

Comment: @Rajesh you didnt read the question, he wants to round it up to the next quarter all the time, not the closest one

Comment: Then what does this mean: **9:18 => 9:15**. Anyways I don't wanna fight. Enjoy and better answer than mine.

Comment: @Rajesh, try my code with `var minutes = (parseInt((18 / 15)) + 1) * 15;` it returns 30. And no need to fight, we are all civilised here right? :P

Comment: @Rajesh I was trying to explain what my old code did. Sorry if that was confusing you.

Comment: **9:18 => 9:15** is the thing that has made confusion for me. If its just about going to next quarter, then your solution is perfect

Comment: Your code cover the minutes, but don't forget to add 1 to hours if minutes = 60 ;)

Comment: @Yep, didnt cover that in my answer ;)

Answer (score 2):

This code will «divide» an hour into 4 interval (0, 1, 2 or 3) (instead of 60). Then multiply it by 15 to have either `00`, `15`, `30` or `45`.

between 0 and 14 minutes, the quarter will show "0", between 15 and 30 it will show "15" and so on.

```
var CurrentDate=new Date();
$("#hours").val(CurrentDate.getHours());
$("#minutes").val(parseInt(CurrentDate.getMinutes()/15)*15);
```

**EDIT** : I misread the question, So to round to the upper quarter, we should use `Math.ceil()` (or `Math.round()` if you prefer round to the closest) I would rather do :

```
var CurrentDate=new Date();
var quarter = Math.ceil(CurrentDate.getMinutes()/15)*15;
$("#minutes").val(quarter%60);
$("#hours").val(parseInt(quarter/60)+CurrentDate.getHours());
```

But usually, this kind of clock show only the past minutes (meaning if hour is past 29 minutes, we usually still display 15 because it's not 30 yet)